# select fields using formatted date

Tags: mysql, sql

My select statement is:

`SELECT date FROM user WHERE date BETWEEN '13/01/2011' AND '28/01/2014'`

The date in my `user` table is structured as i.e.:

`2013-12-10 00:39:22`

So my `SELECT` statement therefore returns `0` records even though there are definitely matches in the table. Is there a way to format it so that it recognizes my date format and returns results in my format?

Comment: Not a dupe, but you've accepted the same solution: `STR_TO_DATE`?

Comment: Then please read Virgnesh's answer carefully and try to understand how it works, don't just simply copy the code. You do need to convert from string to date because you cannot compare dates as strings, just like you cannot do math with "one"+"two" and expect to get "three". Dates are a SQL data type, not just strings.

Comment: @ThreaT, that's exactly the point of marking as duplicate though. Anyone who finds your question will get referred to the actual question they *should* be asking - just as you were by Alvaro.

Comment: Scattering the same info in a hundreds of poorly ranked questions normally makes it harder to find it, not easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT date FROM user 
    WHERE date 
        BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('13/01/2011','%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s') 
        AND STR_TO_DATE('28/01/2014','%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s')
```

## [STR_TO_DATE](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-str_to_date/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the function [str-to-date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)?

Answer (score 0):

Even the following should work

```
SELECT date FROM user WHERE date > '2011-01-13' AND date < '2014-01-28'
```